# Nuxt.js Failed dev script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nuxt.js

I have a site that i've been building using Nuxt.js and I've been loving everything about it but i can't seem to figure out why i'm receiving the following error when I try $npm run dev

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle carlinfitness@1.0.0~predev: carlinfitness@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle carlinfitness@1.0.0~dev: carlinfitness@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle carlinfitness@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle carlinfitness@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/zac/code/carlinFitness/node_modules/.bin:/home/zac/bin:/home/zac/.local/bin:/home/zac/bin:/home/zac/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle carlinfitness@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /home/zac/code/carlinFitness
10 silly lifecycle carlinfitness@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'nuxt' ]
11 silly lifecycle carlinfitness@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle carlinfitness@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: carlinfitness@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid carlinfitness@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/zac/code/carlinFitness
16 verbose Linux 4.13.0-43-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v8.11.2
19 verbose npm  v6.1.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error carlinfitness@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the carlinfitness@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Check any other program running on the same port where you try to run your application (Eg: If you are using default port 3000 check any other program running on port 3000. Then stop that program and run npm run dev again)

Comment: After restarting my system the error went away

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Sk_.  That error message is caused by a process that is running on port 3000.  In may case, I entered http://localhost:3000 in my browser's address bar and behold, my database monitor came up!  I then shut the monitor down and tried again.  This time, $npm run dev ran without a hitch.

Michael